# Increase %e precision with /usr/bin/time shell command (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, time, precision

When I run the time command in shell `time ./myapp` I get an output like the following:

real    0m0.668s

user    0m0.112s

sys 0m0.028s

However,when I run the command `\time -f %e ./myapp` I lose precision and I get:

2.01s

Why is the output not with 3 digits of precision as well? If I use the %E command I also lose precision in the same way. How do i change it to have more precision again, but still only have the seconds being outputted?

I based my research in this 
[Linux / Unix Command: time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking in other forums, one of them gave me the answer I was looking for. It can be found in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70653/increase-e-precision-with-usr-bin-time-shell-command).

Answer (score 2):

You can try `/usr/bin/time -p` instead.  The `-p` option should display the output in the *standard* format.  Here's an example from my MacBook:

```
gondolin% /usr/bin/time find . -name '*.pyc' > /dev/null
        0.10 real         0.04 user         0.05 sys
gondolin% /usr/bin/time -p find . -name '*.pyc' > /dev/null
real         0.10
user         0.04
sys          0.05
```

According to [die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time), then `time` utility should allow you to specify the format in the `TIME` environment variable.  The bash builtin does something similar but uses the `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable instead:

```
bash-3.2$ time find . -name '*.pyc' > /dev/null

real        0m0.155s
user        0m0.051s
sys         0m0.068s
bash-3.2$ export TIMEFORMAT='real    %R
user    %U
sys     %S'
bash-3.2$ time find . -name '*.pyc' > /dev/null
real    0.107
user    0.049
sys     0.058
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: :using /usr/bin/time -p will still give me only 2 digits of precision, not 3. I don't understand how this helps me. All I want is the real execution time in seconds, nothing more :S